# Github Commit not working as it has in the past

Tags: xcode, github, uikit, commit

This may be due to something that I did inadvertently, but when I attempt to Commit using XCODE, I do not get the prompt for a description. rather, I get the screenshot shown in the attachment.  Commit worked fine on March 9.

The only changes that I can recall are a Mac update and an Xcode Simulator update from Apple.

I thought perhaps is was an issue with the remote, but when I doubleclick on the branch, I can see my history, so I do not believe it is corrupted.

I appreciate any help that is offered. Thank you.

Restarted the computer. Closed and restarted XCODE. Attempted to create a new branch but Xcode popped up a screen advising that a branch existed and a new branch is not necessary.

[image]

or at https://i.stack.imgur.com/uclVE.png

Comment: Just For the record, Joe. I would **never, ever, ever** use the git facility that is built-in to Xcode.  In Xcode, turn of source control and never turn it on again, ever.  You can grab the completely free "Sourcetree" Mac app (ie, from github themselves) if you want a graphical interface. Its also well worth learning to use git on the command line.  PS I put in the image for you :)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.  I will check it out.

Comment: Try a different source code control app, Source Tree, Terminal, Github's own source control are some examples.

Comment: I installed Source Tree. I was successful in submitting a Commit. However, when I Push, I get the following error that I'm struggling to understand.  Again, I appreciate the guidance to use a different source control app other than Xcode.  "git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"